# abstractproperty + classmethod decorators in python

Tags: python-2.7, metaclass

I want to enforce childrens to use a classmethod in python2.7.
I tried this:

```
import abc

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    
    @abc.abstractproperty
    def value(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractproperty
    @classmethod
    def text(cls):
        pass

class Imp(Base):

   TEXT = "hi im text"
    @classmethod
    def haba(cls):
        print 'HI'
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return 'asdasd'
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    def text(cls):
        return 'ho ho p'

print Imp.text
print Imp.TEXT
```

But I'm getting this output:
<bound method ABCMeta.? of <class '**main**.Imp'>>
hi im text

How I can properly enforce childrens to implement classmethod properties?
You can see that Imp.TEXT is working but there is no way to enforce creating this member from base class this way

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question a few times I concluded that you want the `cl` method to behave as if it is a property for the class.

First, Python's implementation of abstract method/property checking is meant to be performed at instantiation time only, not at class declaration. I hope you are aware of that.

Second, Python's descriptor protocol allows for the creation of the equivalent of "class properties", although there is no higher level support for that on the language itself - you can create a class which `__get__` method returns your calculated property when the instance argument is None (usually descriptors will return 'self' so that they can be retrieved from the class).

Finally - it is possible that by declaring a custom metaclass being abstract itself, and then declaring it as your class metaclass, abstractproperties will trigger in runtime - let's try that - :

```py
In [1]: import abc                                                                                                           

In [2]: class AbsPropertyMeta(abc.ABC, type): 
   ...:     @abc.abstractproperty 
   ...:     def cl(cls): 
   ...:         return "Ho ho ho" 
   ...:                                                                                                                      

In [3]: class ConcreteExample(metaclass=AbsPropertyMeta): 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:
```

(Note that I will develop the  answer using Python 3, which should be what you should be using in any new project or for learning purposes as well)

So, as for the former example, the property in the metaclass does work as a "class property", but Python does not enforce its redefinition in the class body.

So, if you really need this design, you should create a complete custom metaclass for that, and let go of the abc.ABCMeta mechanisms at all:

```py
from functools import partial

def abstractclassproperty(func):
    func._abstract_property = True
    return func


class clsproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.func(owner)


class ABCAbstractClsProperty(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        new_cls = super(ABCAbstractClsProperty, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        for attr_name in dir(new_cls):  # Dir retrieves attributes from all superclasses
            attr = getattr(new_cls, attr_name)
            if getattr(attr, "im_func", None):   # Python 2 specific normalization.
                attr = attr.im_func
            if getattr(attr, '_abstract_property', False) and new_cls.__dict__.get(attr_name) is not attr:
                raise TypeError("Can't create class {!r}: abstract property {!r} not implemented".format(name, attr_name))
        return new_cls

""" # Python 3:

class A(metaclass=ABCAbstractClsProperty):
    @abstractclassproperty
    def cl(cls):
        pass
"""
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCAbstractClsProperty
    @abstractclassproperty
    def cl(cls):
        pass



try:
    class B(A):
        pass
except TypeError:
    print("Check ok")


class C(A):
    @clsproperty
    def cl(cls):
        return "ho ho ho " + cls.__name__

print(C.cl)
```